# Why doesn't mousePressed() work without setup() in p5.js?

Tags: mouseevent, dom-events, p5.js

In the p5 editor, I was trying to create a simple example that doesn't require a canvas, so I deleted the setup() and draw() functions. I realized that mousePressed() won't work without at least the setup() function being called. I can comment out createCanvas() and mousePressed() works just fine. Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
var luckyNum;

function mousePressed(){
  luckyNum = int(random(0, 100));
  createP("Your lucky number is " + luckyNum + "!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mousePressed()` function works fine without `draw()`, but it does require `setup()`.

Here's an example:

```js
function setup() {
  // empty
}

function mousePressed() {
  background(random(255));
}
```

I'm not sure why this is. It's probably related to some internal initialization that only happens if p5.js detects a `setup()` function.

You might consider switching to pure JavaScript, since you don't seem to need many p5 features. You could attach a click listener to the `<body>` of your page and create a `<p>` element from there.

Comment: Actually, the click is not detected on the canvas--if you try out your example you can click anywhere on the page and the background will still update. 

You're right that draw isn't necessary, but I've tried commenting out the createCanvas() function and mousePressed() still works! However, if I comment out the whole setup function, mousePressed() stops working.

Comment: @bettywhite You're right. That's so weird! I edited my answer.